# How to call C# method in DLL from Runbook in Azure Automation?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-automation

Let's say I create a simple C# class:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static string Start()
    {
        return "Hello World at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
```

Now let's say I compile it into a DLL and want to call the 'Start' method externally.  Through trial & error, I discovered how to do that from PowerShell:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\code\HelloWorld.dll")
[HelloWorld.HelloWorld]::Start()
```

Or this way:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\code\Helloworld.dll"
[HelloWorld.HelloWorld]::Start()
```

Both work fine!

But say I wanted to bundle up this DLL, load it into Azure Automation, and then make a call from a RunBook.  How would I do that?  I have tried several things but keep on getting an error.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: The solution came about by figuring out where Azure stores "global" modules and "user" modules.  Here's the solution that works:

Add-Type -Path "C:\Modules\User\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.dll"
[HelloWorld.HelloWorld]::Start()

Comment: I'd recommend posting it as an answer below so others can see it more clearly!

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following steps to do this:

1) zip the dll file, then click Azure Automation -> ASSETS -> IMPORT MODULES as below screenshot, upload zipped file.
[image]

2) write the test code as below screenshot, we can get the output when we click "TEST"
[image]

Comment: I did the same thing for DACPAC deployment using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll` but it doesn't work in Azure Automation. Any idea why? Link - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1aa631fe-be32-4915-a3a8-c055575fe94e/how-to-deploy-a-dacpac-using-azure-runbook-automation?forum=azureautomation#1aa631fe-be32-4915-a3a8-c055575fe94e

Comment: @Jambor I tried in same way but i get error as "Invalid Module Structure" . What could be fix